# Get the difference of files between two branches from a list of files by one author?

Tags: git

My problem is I have two branches and I want to compare the diference between files between those two branches, lest call **b1** and **b2** the branches.

At **b1** I have 10 commits by diferente authors:

- c1 - author1
- c2 - author2
- c3 - author2
- c4 - author3
- c5 - author4
- c6 - author2
- c7 - author1
- c8 - author3
- c9 - author1
- c10 - author1

At **b2** I just have one commit which is a merge
- Merge - author1

I need to get te list of files modified by one author at **b1** and compare the result these files with branch **b2** logging the difference of the files between those branches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command below get all the files committed by Alexandre Mendes at **b1** and make a diff between these files with the branches that supposed to be compared **b1** and **b2**.

```
for i in $(git log --pretty="%H" --author="Alexandre Mendes" b1 | while read commit_hash; do git show --oneline --name-only $commit_hash | tail -n+2; done | sort | uniq); 
do git --no-pager diff b2..b1 $i;
done
```